# Reeb Foliation for 3-Sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, foliations

I was trying to prove the following statement:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the Reeb foliation of $S^3$ and let $\phi$ : $S^3$ $\rightarrow$ $N$ be a continuous map whose restriction to each leaf of $\mathcal{F}$ is constant. Show that $\phi$ is constant.

Considering that the Reeb foliation of the 3-sphere comes from the foliation of two solid tori where the inner leaves approach the boundary (which is also a leaf) of the torus asymptotically, my idea was:

Consider a point $p$ on the boundary of the torus. Now, $\phi$($p$)=$q$. Take an open set U around $q$. $\phi^{-1}(U)$ will be an open set around $p$ and since the inner leaves tend asymptotically to the boundary of the torus, this neighborhood of $p$ will contain points from other leaves. We can make $U$ as small as we wish and the same thing will still happen. Therefore, the function will have the same value on every leaf and so it is constant on the whole manifold. I'm having some difficulty in making precise the fact that the leaves will always tend to points on the boundary, but it seems obvious from the parameterization I'm looking at: 
\begin{equation}
(x,y) \rightarrow (x,y,log \left( \frac{c}{f(x^2+y^2)}\right))
\end{equation}
with $c<0$ and $f(0)=-1$, $f(1)=0$ and $f$ is an increasing function. Note that this parameterization corresponds to leaves inside a cylinder. Then after taking the quotient it induces a foliation on the solid 2-torus.

Comment: So if you've seen rigorously that every leaf approaches the boundary leaf asymptotically, can you prove that the function must be constant?

Comment: Yes, I think so... I would just have to use continuity. If i take any open set around some point on the boundary it will contain points from the leaves.

Comment: OK, but that won't do, as the values on the leaves could just be close to the value on the boundary leaf. You need something a bit more precise.

Comment: Maybe if i could find some sequence of points on the inner leaves that converges to the boundary. That could work?

Comment: If you do it right, yes. Alternatively, I might suggest you do a proof by contradiction and get a concrete $\varepsilon>0$ to play with.

Comment: The point is to give a precise mathematical sense of the sentence "the inner leaves approach the boundary" . In fact, this means that given a leaf, there exists a sequence of points in this leaf converging to a point in the torus. Tthis yields the conclusion.